# How can I toggle among flags when clicking on a <td> element or a <div> within it using AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

The image below depicts how the table looks like right now, with some test data. Under "IMAGE" will be (thumbnails of) images of invoices and bills. The page is going to be used for accounting.

[image: Just some test data]

In `<td>` I put:

```
echo '<td><div  id="currency" onclick="refreshClick()">'. $currency . '</div></td>';
```

This is the script itself:

```
<script>
           function refreshClick() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "assets/scripts/php/currency.php",
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#currency').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
</script>
```

so the data is loaded from a php script. But this solution doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try somthing like this:

Your table:

the **id** should be unique and it wont be on multiple rows, so use a **class** and target that **td div** with **$(this)** in jQuery.

```
<td><div class="currency">'. $currency . '</div></td>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.currency', function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url: "assets/scripts/php/currency.php",
            success: function(data){
                $(this).html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it soon but it makes sense.